# Sending Email using SMTP gmail in CodeIgniter from website

Tags: php, codeigniter, email

I'm stuck on my problem to send email with codeigniter.

I've already done successful sending gmail, but the problem is the recipient and the sender are the same. I want this email received to me from sender in website,

There is my **Controller** :

```
public function index(){        
    $this->sendEmail(); 
    $this->load->view('content_contact');
}
public function sendEmail(){
    $this->load->helper(array('form', 'url'));
    $this->load->library('email');

    //konfigurasi email
    $config = array();
    $config['charset'] = 'utf-8';
    $config['useragent'] = 'Codeigniter';
    $config['protocol']= "smtp";
    $config['mailtype']= "html";
    $config['smtp_host']= "ssl://smtp.gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_port']= 465;
    $config['smtp_timeout']= "5";
    $config['smtp_user']= "my_email$gmail.com";
    $config['smtp_pass']= "my_pass";            
    $config['crlf']="\r\n";
    $config['newline']="\r\n";

    $config['wordwrap'] = TRUE;
    $this->load->view('content_contact');

    $this->email->initialize($config);
    $this->email->from($this->input->post('from'));
    $this->email->to("my_email@gmail.com");
    $this->email->subject($this->input->post('subject'));
    $this->email->message($this->input->post('isi'));

    if($this->email->send()){
        echo "pengiriman email Success";
    }
    else{
        echo "pengiriman email Failed";
    }

}
```

And This is my **View** : `content_contact.php`
[content_contact.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/udeZS.png)

Comment: what is your error?

Comment: i dont have any error, but the problem is that email was sent by me and received to me too

Answer (score 1):

use below mentioned solution

```
$config = Array(
    'protocol' => 'smtp',
    'smtp_host' => 'ssl://smtp.googlemail.com',
    'smtp_port' => 465,
    'smtp_user' => 'my_email@gmail.com',
    'smtp_pass' => 'yourpassword',
    'mailtype'  => 'html', 
    'charset'   => 'utf-8',
    'wordwrap'  => TRUE
);
$this->load->library('email', $config);
```